# Reverse strings in array objectivec

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse NSString text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720191/reverse-nsstring-text)

i am new on objectovec. i have a array having strings. how to reverse each string?

which method of `NSArray` and `NSstring` will help me out?

i want reversed string in the array.

thanks

Comment: Mmmm... smells like homework.

Comment: You should take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720191/reverse-nsstring-text. Hope it helps!

Comment: You want string to be reversed or array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method that will return a reversed string.

```
-(NSString *)reverseString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *reverseString=[NSString new];
    for (NSInteger i=string.length-1; i>-1; i--) {
        reverseString=[reverseString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c",[string characterAtIndex:i]];
    }
    return reverseString;
}
```

In your any of the method :

```
NSMutableArray *names=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"anoop",@"johnson",@"wasim",nil];
for (NSInteger i=0; i<names.count; i++) {
    names[i]=[self reverseString:names[i]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",names);
```

Comment: Maybe the string function won't work with four byte characters? Maybe `substringWithRange:` is safer?

Comment: It would be better to use `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` with the `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` and `NSStringEnumerationReverse `options. Otherwise it'll break when you have emojis or certain cjk characters in your string.

Comment: @omz: yes u r right... but i m still learning blocks.  and as the user wanted to reverse the contents of array... so i used another for with name[i]... can i shorten its length?

Comment: Btw, your method is also very inefficient when it comes to memory usage. You're creating a new string for every character. Use `NSMutableString` instead and append to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str=textEntered.text;//
    NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<[str length];i++)
    {
        [temp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[temp reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
    NSString *reverseString=@"";
    for(int i=0;i<[temp count];i++)
    {
        reverseString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",reverseString,[temp objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",reverseString);
```

**AnOther way for revers string** `NSStringEnumerationOptions`

```
- (NSString *)reverseString:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableString *reversedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSRange fullRange = [string rangeOfString:string];
    NSStringEnumerationOptions enumerationOptions = (NSStringEnumerationReverse | NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences);
    [string enumerateSubstringsInRange:fullRange options:enumerationOptions usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [reversedString appendString:substring];
    }];
    return reversedString;
}
```

Comment: Using `rangeOfString:` to get the full range is completely unnecessary and inefficient (that method is for *searching* strings). Just use `NSMakeRange(0, string.length)`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help

```
NSString *str=textEntered.text;//
    NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<[str length];i++)
    {
        [temp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[temp reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
    NSString *reverseString=@"";
    for(int i=0;i<[temp count];i++)
    {
        reverseString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",reverseString,[temp objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",reverseString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
unichar c[yourstring.Length];
    NSRange raneg={0,yourstring.Length};
    [yourstring getCharacters:c range:raneg];
//c will be an array of your string do what ever you wish
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one to reverse your string and then store back to your array at same index.

```
-(NSString*)reverseString:(NSString*)string {
    NSMutableString *reversedString;
    int length = [string length];
    reversedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];
    while (length--) {
            [reversedString appendFormat:@"%c", [string characterAtIndex:length]];
    }
    return reversedString;
}
```

**But if you have mutable string then you can create a category**

```
@interface NSMutableString (Reverse)
- (void)reverseString;
@end

@implementation NSMutableString (Reverse)

- (void)reverseString {
    for (int i = 0; i < self.length/2; i++) {
        int l = self.length - 1 - i;

        NSRange iRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1);
        NSRange lRange = NSMakeRange(l, 1);

        NSString *iStr = [self substringWithRange:iRange];
        NSString *lStr = [self substringWithRange:lRange];

        [self replaceCharactersInRange:iRange withString:lStr];
        [self replaceCharactersInRange:lRange withString:iStr];
    }
}

@end
```

And then you can use this category method like this

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[@"hello" mutableCopy], [@"Do it now" mutableCopy], [@"Test string, 123 123" mutableCopy], nil];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
[arr makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(reverseString)];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```