# How can I generate this kind of string pattern as key for encryption

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

Hi I am trying to generate this kind of `NSString` pattern  my real `string` is "`abcdefgh`"  I want to take the corresponding bytes by using

```
NSData *data=[mystring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
NSLog(@"%d",[data bytes]);
```

Copy these values into the `byte array` and limit total array size as `24bit`.

then from that I want to create following pattern

```
"abcdefgh efghabcd hgfedcba"
```

How can I generate this kind of key ?

please help me

Comment: I hope you're not trying to [roll your own crypto](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/2210/20774)

Comment: just tell me how can i do that string operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work. The logic for reversedString taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6730329/767730)

```
#import "NSString+CustomCrypto.h"

@implementation NSString (CustomCrypto)

- (NSString *)reversedString{

    NSMutableString *reversedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[self length]];

    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[self length])
                                 options:(NSStringEnumerationReverse | NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences)
                              usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                  [reversedString appendString:substring];
                              }];

    return [NSString stringWithString:reversedString];
}

- (NSString *)splicedString{

    NSInteger index = [self length]/2;

    NSString *subString = [self substringFromIndex:index];
    NSString *secondString = [self substringToIndex:index];

    return [subString stringByAppendingString:secondString];
}

- (NSString *)customCryptoString{

    NSString *splicedString = [self splicedString];
    NSString *reversedString = [self reversedString];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",self, splicedString, reversedString];
}
```

Call the category method of string

```
NSLog(@"%@",[@"abcdefgh" customCryptoString]);
```

> Output : abcdefgh efghabcd hgfedcba