# Reverse a double value

Tags: objective-c, double, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a double value like this:

Input: 1020304050......  Output: 5040302010 
the group of 2 digits remain in the same order. So 10 doesn't become 01. or 53 doesn't become 35.

The input will always have even number of digits, so pairing isn't an issue.

The 2 adjacent digits are actually a code number for a function. And I want to maintain that so I can apply that function again.

```
double temp = 0.0;
    double Singlefilter=1;
    double reverseString=0;
    temp=filtersequence;

    while (temp>0)
    {


        Singlefilter=fmod(temp, 100.00);
        temp=temp/100;

        reverseString=(reverseString+Singlefilter)*100;
        NSLog(@"reversed string of filter %f",reverseString);

    }
```

But I have no idea why this isn't working. This is generating randomly very very big values.

---

[This question has been replaced by [Reverse a double value while maintaining 2 adjacent digits in same format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143162/reverse-a-double-value-while-maintaining-2-adjacent-digits-in-same-format)]

Comment: What's that `filtersequence` right before the `while` loop?

Comment: Your code is pretty badly worded too I'm afraid - a `double` variable called `reverseString`?!

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to first convert it to a string and then reversing it. It was way too lengthy that way.

Comment: @Blackbird...it is a 16 digit number.

Comment: You are probably not expecting `5040302010` as the output, but `504030201`.

Comment: I want output as 50403020

Comment: Ok, so you always want to process groups of two digits? Like: 98.76.54.32.10 -> 10.32.54.76.98 (dots inserted for convenience of presentation)?

Comment: yeah..exactly like that.

Comment: Do you mind putting that in your question, since apparently it comes as a surprise to everybody here.

Comment: To be honest you're probably better off creating a new question as its completely different from what you originally asked for!

Comment: Thanks for helping guys. Can you please stop down-voting now? I've  corrected the question too and I'm still being down-voted so I can't ask any more question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off just converting it to a string and reversing it.

```
NSString *inputString = [@(input) stringValue]; // Eg 1230
NSMutableString *reversedString = [NSMutableString string];
NSInteger charIndex = [inputString length];
while (charIndex > 0) {
    charIndex--;
    NSRange subStrRange = NSMakeRange(charIndex, 1);
    [reversedString appendString:[inputString substringWithRange:subStrRange]];
}
double result = [reversedString doubleValue]; // Eg 0321 -> 321
// Go back to NSString to get the missing length
NSString *resultString = [@(result) stringValue]; // Eg. 321

// Multiple by factors of 10 to add zeros
result *= exp(10, [inputString length] - [resultString length]); // 3210

NSLog(@"reversed value %f", result);
```

Reverse string method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6720235/849645).

Comment: The issue with this is that he does not seem to want a pure reversal, which would lose 0's when converting back and forth. He is keeping trailing zeroes static at the end. That said, using strings with a slightly modified algorithm is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Dima do you mean he wants `100` to be converted to `001`? To be honest I think he means `5040302001` in his output otherwise he's doing something mental and not just reversing!

Comment: Yes, it's only 2 digit..so 1122 to 2211

Comment: @rbk see my above comment, was your output example incorrect?

Comment: @Rich...I think I tried this solution a couple of minutes ago. What this does is input: 102030...output 030201 .... where as what I want is 302010

Comment: @Rich based on his sample input/output, 100 would actually just stay 100. Looks like he wants to keep trailing 0's on the right and flip everything else, so that converting back and forth maintains consistent results. That said, I have no idea what a possible use-case for this is.

Comment: @rbk I've updated my answer, I think that's what you want to do at the end - it's a little crude, but then I have no idea what you're doing this for! It basically shifts the result by powers of 10 till the length of the result is the same as the original string

Comment: @Dima I'm glad its not just me that thinks this is bizarre! :)

Comment: Edited to remove the `if` statement as `10^0 = 1` (I also corrected to use `exp` instead of multiplying - its late!)

Comment: @Dima: I'm working on a photo editing application. So every time a filter is applied it's code is added to the sequence. Now when I wish to apply this custom filter..I want it to apply the filters in the same sequence. So if I reverse the saved list of sequence..I have to simply take the last 2 digits out and apply that filter.

Comment: Stop storing that information in a `double`, @rbk. Use an appropriate data type like an array.

Comment: I have to store this double in an array eventually. So.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "math.h"

void outputGroupReversed(double filtersequence)
{
    double reverseString = 0.0;
    double temp = filtersequence;

    while (temp > 0.0)
    {
        double groupMultiplier = 100.0;
        double singleFilter = fmod(temp, groupMultiplier);
        temp = floor(temp / groupMultiplier);

        reverseString = reverseString * groupMultiplier + singleFilter;
    }

    NSLog(@"reversed string of filter %f", reverseString);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        outputGroupReversed(1020304050.0);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not handle input with a fractional part correctly, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to store 2-digit decimal integers packed together as a single numeric value you would be better of using `uint64_t` - unsigned long 64 bit integers rather than `double`. That will store 9 pairs of two decimal digits precisely which appears to be one more than you need (you mention 16 digits in a comment).

As long as the *numeric* value of the packed pairs is not important, just that you can pack 8 2-digit decimal numbers (i.e. 0 -> 99) into a single numeric value, then you can do better. A 64-bit integer is 8 pairs of 2-hexadecimal digit numbers, or 8 8-bit bytes, so you can store 8 values 0 -> 99 one per byte. Now adding and extracting values becomes bit-shifts (`>>` & `<<` operators) by 8 and bitwise-or (`|`) and bitwise-and (`&`). This at least makes it clear you are packing values in, which divide & remainder do not.

But there is another payoff, your "reverse" operation now becomes a single call to `CFSwapInt64()` which reverses the order of the bytes.

*However having said the above, you really should look at your model and consider another data type for what you are doing - long gone are the days when programs had to pack multiple values into words to save space.*

For example, why not just use a (C) array of 8-bit (`uint8_t values[8]`) integers? If you require you can place that in a `struct` and pass it around as a single value.

Comment: Moved this answer to [follow on question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143162/reverse-a-double-value-while-maintaining-2-adjacent-digits-in-same-format/23144004#23144004)