# Reverse NSString recursively in category

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, objective-c-category

I made this **category** for reversing an `NSString` in a **recursive** way. I'm getting the correct answer. But I'm not sure if this is okay with **memory management**. I don't know much about memory management in Objective-C.

Any other efficient way would be highly admirable.

```
-(NSString *)reverseString{
    if ([self length]<2) {
        return self;
    } else {
        return [[[self substringFromIndex:1] reverseString] stringByAppendingString:[self substringToIndex:1]];
    }
}
```

However, this question is similar to [Reverse NSString text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720191/reverse-nsstring-text) but not the duplicate because here I'm implementing it with recursion. And I specifically asked about the memory consumption not for any code example.

Comment: You will likely cause a stack overflow trying to reverse a long string (thousands of letters). And your code will produce a bad string with any Unicode characters that are encoded as more than one character.

Comment: Honestly, using this recursive algorithm is probably one of the least useful ways to reverse a string. The duplicate linked by Sanjit has much better approaches than this algorithm.

Comment: Just for fun, try reversing a string containing an Emoji. As written, space and time requirement are O (n^2) where n is the length of the original string. A string of 100,000 characters will bring a Mac to its knees.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment @gnasher729 . I tried with an emoji and in vein . But it was fun literally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using recursion to reverse a string is an interesting thought exercise, but it is goning to be very slow and a dreadful wasteful of memory. You need to create 2n temporary strings. (where n is the number of characters in your string) n of those strings are only 1 character long, and the other n strings are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Etc. Characters, up to n-1.

(Memory allocation is very slow.)

Plus you create n stack frames. As rmaddy says in his comment, you'll likely cause a stack overflow for very long strings.

If you are doing this to learn about recursion, fine. Otherwise, toss this approach completely and write code that loops through the array backwards, appending each character to a mutable string.

Comment: Thanks for making me understood what's under the hood. I couldn't think like you said. Very descriptive answer to my question . And yes, I've just started learning Objective-C, so I thought "what about with basic recursion" and ended up with this.