# Want to reverse some specific word form given string using NSString in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c as well as to iOS.
I have one string like this

```
NSString *string1 = @"My name is john";
```

I want to reverse only 'john' to 'nhoj'.
Please Help me!!!.
Thank You

Comment: have u tried anything.. put it here

Comment: What have you tried? How do you detect which word to reverse? Did you do some research: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720191/reverse-nsstring-text ?

Comment: Check my answer user7018875

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. 
May following snippet help you.

```
    NSString *string1 = @"My name is john";

NSArray *arr = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSString *temp_sre = [arr objectAtIndex:arr.count - 1];

int len = [temp_sre length];
NSMutableString *reverseName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:len];
for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    [reverseName appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[temp_sre characterAtIndex:i]]];
}
NSLog(@"reverseName = %@",reverseName);

NSMutableArray *final_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
final_array = arr.mutableCopy;
[final_array removeLastObject];
[final_array insertObject:reverseName atIndex:final_array.count];

NSString *final_string = [final_array componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@"FInal String = %@",final_string);
```

Comment: Hey Maddy, Your Program Working fine but it displayed only reverse word 'nhoj',I want whole string like "My name is nhoj".And please don't replace in array ,Because string may be long ,so i wanna without array.  thank you

Comment: you need output like this : "nhoj si eman yM"?

Comment: I want output like this "My name is nhoj"

Comment: hey @user7018875 i update my ans. according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try This, It will produce your desire output.

```
NSString *strName = @"My name is john" ;

NSArray *arrStringPart = [strName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *strToReverse = [arrStringPart objectAtIndex:arrStringPart.count - 1];


int len = (int)[strToReverse length];
NSMutableString *mutStrReverce = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:strName.length];

for(int i=0;i<arrStringPart.count-1;i++)
{
    [mutStrReverce appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[arrStringPart objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    [mutStrReverce appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[strToReverse characterAtIndex:i]]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",mutStrReverce);
```