# Reverse String with for-loop in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

Just now learning objective-c and I am trying to reverse a string using a simple for loop. I am not sure what part I am missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
NSString *input = @"Hello world";

NSMutableString *reversedString = [NSMutableString string];

for(int i =0; i<input.length;i--){

    [reversedString appendString:input];

}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? @"dlrow olleH"?

Comment: Several ideas here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720191/reverse-nsstring-text), but I won't close as dup because I don't see any answer there better than @Sulthan 's "Another way", which I think is the shortest computational trip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors there.

First, the `for` loop. You have to start with the last index and end at zero:

```
for (NSInteger i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Second, you are always appending the whole string, instead of the character.

```
NSString *character = [input substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
[reversedString appendString:character];
```

(I am taking a substring starting at index `i` with length `1`).

Another way would be:

```
unichar character = [input characterAtIndex:i];
[reversedString appendFormat:@"%C", character];
```

A little bit more advanced option would be:

```
[input enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, input.length)
                          options:(NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences | NSStringEnumerationReverse)
                       usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                   [reversedString appendString:substring];
                               }];
```

Comment: I like the second idea.  It could start out even better by converting the input using `[input UTF8String]`, then `character = convertedInput[i]`

Comment: @danh Nope. `UTF8String` is a terrible idea if your string is not ASCII. Note the difference between `unichar` and `char.

Comment: OP's string is ASCII

Comment: @danh It's not the correct tool for the job. Reversing a string is not done by reversing its bytes.

Comment: You made the point well (and twice) that strings aren't always representable as an array of bytes.  I agree, excluding a wide variety of circumstances such as this one.  I stand by my up-vote.

Comment: @Sulthan - you are correct, reversing a string is not done by reversing its bytes. It is also true that reversing a string is not done by reversing its UTF-16 16-bit words... Your "a little bit more advanced" is the answer.