# objective c array length from string size

Tags: objective-c

I am rookie to programming. So pardon my ignorance. I am learning objective c.

I am using below syntax for initializing an array. But I don't see it being initialized. What mistake am I making? Help of any sort is appreciated.

```
-(NSString *) reverseString: (NSString *) reverseThis {

int len = [reverseThis length];
const char * c1 = [reverseThis UTF8String]; 
char *c2[len]; // This is the array I am trying to initialize.
int count;
for(int i=length; i > 0; i--) {
  c2[count] = c1[i];
  count++;
} 
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", c2];    
}
```

Comment: Well you are just setting the size of the array and populating it with nothing.

Comment: Also if ```[reverseThis length]``` returns 0, then the array won't store any data unless you re-initialise it.

Comment: If you are trying to reverse a string, check for instance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720191/.  And if you are a rookie, why not learn Swift, then it is even easier to get a reverse string.

Comment: `char *c2[len];` only declares the variable, an array of `char*`. It's like `int len;`. The problem is the *, you want an array of `char`. Don't ignore the warnings of the compiler, they tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: That is my complete code. @Supertecnoboff - [reverseThis length] doesn't return 0.

Comment: @Willeke - I tried both c2*[len] and c2[len]; c2 isn't holding any values, only time c2 holds value is when I hard code c2[10];

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Fix the errors and the warnings first.